# React native statusBar

Tags: react-native

I am trying to style the `statusBar`, on my android emulator, its too deep and green in colour. How can I set the height?

```html
 render() {
    const { navigationState, dispatch } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="#000" />
        <View style={styles.appBar} />
        <View style={styles.content} />

        <NavigationStack
          navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch,
            state: navigationState,
            addListener
          })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;
const APPBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 44 : 56;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  statusBar: {
    height: STATUSBAR_HEIGHT
  },
  appBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#79B45D",
    height: APPBAR_HEIGHT
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#33373B"
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
render() {
    const { navigationState, dispatch } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
 />

        <NavigationStack
          navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch,
            state: navigationState,
            addListener
          })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```